# Special character CASE expression

Tags: postgresql, databricks

I an trying to create a CASE expression to identify a special character and then transform the data to account for variations in email addresses.

So far I have my CASE expression built as follows:

```
case when b.useremailaddress like '%_%' then 2
   when b.useremailaddress like '%.%' then 1
   Else 0
End as special_char
```

example of the email formats.

```
first.lastname@somewhere.com
first_lastname@somewhere.com
```

when I use the case logic in databricks both emails return the value 2 from the CASE expression.  I want one based on the `.` separator to return the first example, and the underscore separator to return the second example.

Comment: Read [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) and [Expression Evaluation Rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL)  for why `CASE` does not necessarily to do left to right evaluation.

Comment: Also read [LIKE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-like/). The expression you have (%_%) actually says *find any number of characters, including 0, followed by 1 character, followed by any number of characters, including 0*. This matches every string that contains at least 1 character.

Comment: Thank you both for the responses.  I actually found the following through a little more research paired with y'alls reading suggestions. (https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/10965.962991238%40sss.pgh.pa.us)
The concept is '%\\_%'

Answer (score 0):

The underscore (`_`) is a special character in `LIKE` patterns; it matches a single arbitrary character. To match a literal underscore, escape it with a backslash in the `LIKE` pattern:

```
LIKE '%\_%'
```